# How to express a power series in closed form

Tags: sequences-and-series, roots-of-unity

I am trying to express the power series $x + x^4/4! + x^7/7! + \cdots$ in closed form;

I have already worked out the power series $1 + x^3/3! + x^6/6! + \cdots$ to be $(e^x + e^{x(2\pi i/3)} + e^{x(2\pi i/3)^2})/3$ using the roots of unity and the series for $e^x$ to get there, and I think I need to somehow "cycle" through to get to my desired closed form but I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not integrate the series you already have?

Comment: I'd like to formulate it using roots of unity if possible

Comment: The general technique is called series multisection.

Comment: @Sophie Thanks for the pointer. Didn't know it by that name, but it is indeed listed as such [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesMultisection.html).

Comment: @HarrisonW. What is that "roots of unity" technique you're talking about? Can you tell me some more or point to the sources where I could read more about it? Seems interesting. (Not the roots of unity themselves – I know about these – but its application to decoding power series to functions.)

Comment: OK never mind, found it ;)  Your first example can be simplified to: $f(x)
\;=\;
1+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}+\frac{x^{12}}{12!} + \cdots
\;=\;
\frac{e^{x} \,+\, 2e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x)}{3}$

Comment: The other example simplifies to: $f(x)
\;=\;
x+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^{10}}{10!}+\frac{x^{13}}{13!} + \cdots
\;=\;
\frac{e^{x} \,+\, \left(\sqrt{3}\cdot\sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x) -\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x) \right)\cdot e^{-\frac{x}{2}} }{3}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> worked out the power series $1 + x^3/3! + x^6/6! + \cdots$ to be $(e^x + e^{x(2\pi i/3)} + e^{x(4\pi i/3)})/3$

Not so, with $\omega = e^{2 \pi i / 3}$ the correct expression is $\,\frac{1}{3}(e^x + e^{\omega x} + e^{\omega^2 x}) = 1 + x^3/3! \,+ x^6/6! \,+ \,\cdots\,$

Then you can take the same idea to the next step. Hint:

- $\,\frac{1}{3}(e^x + \omega e^{\omega x} + \omega^2 e^{\omega^2 x}) = x^2/2! \,+ x^5/5! \,+ x^8/8! \,+\,\cdots\,$
- $\,\frac{1}{3}(e^x + \omega^2 e^{\omega x} + \omega e^{\omega^2 x}) = x \,+ x^4/4! \,+ x^7/7! \,+ \,\cdots\,$

Comment: For those later readers who do not know the technique used for summing the series in the first place (like me before reading this post), see Theorem 1.1 of these [online notes](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~goran/research-reports/psrr10-2013.pdf). +1 vote to both this answer and the OP for teaching me something new.

Comment: I have amended my question now to correct it, thanks for pointing that out, was silly of me. You set $\omega = e^{2\pi i/3}$ in your answer but I believe you meant to set $\omega = 2\pi i/3$.

I've also attempted a full solution of my own, if you don't mind verifying I am correct in saying integration / double differentiation are both just as valid.

Comment: @HarrisonWilde `I believe you meant to set ...` No, I meant just what I wrote: $\omega = e^{2\pi i / 3}$ $\ne 2 \pi i /3$ is a complex cube root of unity.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies to the two earlier answers, I made a typo - as they noticed - in my original question; the question now reflects what the closed form for $1 + x^3/3! + x^6/6! + \cdots$ should be. From that we can either integrate or differentiate twice to get my desired closed form for $x + x^4/4! + x^7/7! + \cdots$ as follows:

---

By integration:

Notice that the infinite sequence $x + x^4/4! + x^7/7! + \cdots = \int^x_0 1 + x^3/3! + x^6/6! + \cdots dx$

For efficiency, let $\omega=2\pi i/3$, then,

$$\int^x_0 1 + x^3/3! + x^6/6! + \cdots dx = \int^x_0 \frac 1 3 (e^x+e^{\omega x} + e^{\omega^2 x}) \, dx$$

$$=[e^x/3 +e^{\omega x}/3\omega +e^{\omega^2 x}/3\omega^2]^x_0$$

$$=e^x/3 +e^{\omega x}/3\omega +e^{\omega^2 x}/3\omega^2-1/3-1/3\omega-1/3\omega^2$$

$$=\omega^2e^x/3\omega^2+\omega e^{\omega x}/3\omega^2+e^{\omega^2 x}/3\omega^2-(\omega^2+\omega+1(1/3))$$

$$=\omega^2e^x/3\omega^2+\omega e^{\omega x}/3\omega^2+e^{\omega^2 x}/3 \omega^2$$

---

By differentiating twice:

Notice that the infinite sequence $$x + x^4/4! + x^7/7! + \cdots = d/dx(d/dx( 1 + x^3/3! + x^6/6! + \cdots ))$$

For efficiency, let $\omega=2\pi i/3$, then,

$$\frac d {dx} \left(\frac d {dx}( 1 + x^3/3! + x^6/6! + \cdots )\right) = \frac d {dx}\left(\frac d {dx} \left(\frac 1 3(e^x+e^{\omega x} + e^{\omega^2 x}) \right) \right)$$

$$= \frac d {dx}(e^x/3+\omega e^{\omega x}/3+\omega^2 e^{\omega^2 x}/3) = e^x/3+\omega^2e^{\omega x}/3 +\omega e^{\omega^2 x}/3$$

---

The answers from both are of course equivalent.

Comment: For the starting formula to hold true you need to define $\omega$ to be a complex cube root of unity, so that $\omega^3=1$ and $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$. Then powers other than multiples of $3$ "cancel out" when you add the three series $e^x+e^{\omega x}+e^{\omega^2x}$.

Comment: @dxiv Of course my bad, I got caught up in the closed form involving exp(something) as well, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Following David Quinn's hint:

$$f(x)=1+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}+\dots=\frac13(e^x+e^{x(2\pi i/3)}+e^{x(4\pi i/3})$$

Notice that

$$\int_0^x1+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\frac{t^6}{6!}+\dots\ dt=x+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+\dots$$

And that

$$\int_0^x\frac13(e^t+e^{t(2\pi i/3)}+e^{t(4\pi i/3})\ dt=\frac13e^x+\frac1{2\pi i}e^{x(2\pi i/3)}+\frac1{4\pi i}e^{x(4\pi i/3)}+\frac{3i}{4\pi}-\frac13$$

Thus,

$$x+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+\dots=\frac13e^x+\frac1{2\pi i}e^{x(2\pi i/3)}+\frac1{4\pi i}e^{x(4\pi i/3)}+\frac{3i}{4\pi}-\frac13$$

---

Note that you probably won't be able to express it in terms of the roots of unity as nicely since it isn't of the form

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{kn}}{(kn)!}$$

Comment: The first line comes from the OP but I don't think it's right.

Comment: @dxiv I honestly didn't want to check, so I hope you get the honestly better answer.

Comment: That's completely understandable, I only meant for later readers to be warned that your derivation is good, but OP's starting point was not.